# Converting stored binary data to hex?

Tags: c, string, binary, hex

char string[100] = "000000000000000000010000000000"  this is the data i have and the data is in bits that 4 individual 8 bits that is when we split string[100]
we get,   00000000  00000000  00000100  00000000 can anyone help me convert it to hex value using C language?

for the above string ,after converting it to hex we need to get " 00 00 04 00 " so similarly based on the input i need to get a desired output.

Comment: You'll need at least one loop.

Comment: This isn't binary, it's a string representing a binary number. Big difference.

Answer (score 2):

No need to re-invent the wheel, just use `strtol`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
  char string[100] = "000000000000000000010000000000";
  printf("%.8lx\n", strtol(string,0,2));
}
```

It you need to group it as bytes with space in between:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
  char string[100] = "000000000000000000010000000000";
  char byte_str[100];
  sprintf(byte_str, "%.8lx\n", strtol(string,0,2));
  for(size_t i=0; i<strlen(byte_str); i+=2)
  {
    printf("%c%c ", byte_str[i], byte_str[i+1]);
  }
}
```

This might not be the most efficient code but it literally took me a few minutes to write.

Answer (score 0):

If it an exercise to learn how to convert and split number into bytes without fancy library functions:

```
unsigned convert(const char * restrict str)
{
    unsigned result = 0;
    while(*str)
    {
        result *= 2;
        result += *str++ == '1';
    }
    return result;
}

#define MASK ((1 << CHAR_BIT) - 1)
#define GETBYTE(val, index) (((val) >> ((sizeof(val) - (index) - 1) * CHAR_BIT)) & MASK)


void print(const unsigned val)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < sizeof(val); index++)
    {
        printf("%02x%c", GETBYTE(val, index), (index == sizeof(val) - 1) ? '\n' : ' ');
    }
}

int main (void)
{
  char string[100] = "000000000000000000010000000000";
  unsigned val = convert(string);
  printf("0x%08x\n", val);
  print(val);
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/18G7r37TW